# Typescript Dictionary with C# API

Tags: c#, typescript, dictionary

So I've been beating my head to this issue and I'm hoping someone can help me.

I have a C# API that returns a dictionary structured as follows:

```
{
    "5/24/2021": [
        {
            "Grouping": "Label0",
            "Count": 71
        },
        {
            "Grouping": "Label1",
            "Count": 44
        },
        {
            "Grouping": "Label2",
            "Count": 18
        },
        {
            "Grouping": "Label3",
            "Count": 34
        }        
    ]
}
```

In **typescript** I created a dictionary that looks as follows

```
import { KeyValuePair } from './keyValuePair';

export interface Dictionary{
  [key:string]: KeyValuePair[];
    
}

export interface KeyValuePair {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

I then use `HttpClient.get<Dictionary>( '<someurl>').subscribe((data) => {});` to retrieve and load the data and when I check `data` the values are there. However when I try to access `data.key`, I get an "undefined" error. How can I retrieve the data in the object?

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the data like this:

```
data["key"]
```

In order to find all keys you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
Object.keys(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked in helping me retrieve the collection. Now the collection is not recognized as a KeyValuePair interface. I can loop through and build the collection but shouldn't it know that it's a keyvaluepair type?